# Наложение элементов с прозрачным фоном

Tags: html, css, background

Имеются два блока, один внутри другого.

```css
.first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5)
}

.second {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Есть ли возможность убрать эффект наложения цветов или ограничить фон внешнего элемента границами внутреннего?

Например прозрачное модальное окно. Фон затенения подмешивается к фону самого окна. При этом само окно может содержать в себе другие блоки, которым тоже хотелось бы задать прозрачный фон другого цвета.

Comment: Что значит эффект наложения?

Comment: Смешивания иначе говоря.

Answer (score 1):

Опишите задачу подробнее. Пока могу предложить вам несколько обходных путей, исходя из предоставленного примера:

- убрать большой блок, а вместо него добавить два маленьких блока, формирующих выступающую часть
- использовать результирующие цвета после применения прозрачности и задавать их, отключив прозрачность. Достаточно сделать это только для маленького блока
- и третий, самый удачный, на мой взгляд. Под маленький блок сделать белую подложку

Если вы больше раскажете о проблеме, то можно будет поискать более элегантные решения

```css
.first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5)
}

.second {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5)
}

.option_one {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    position:relative;
}
.option_one div {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
.helper_a {
    position:absolute;
    width:25px;
    height:100px;
    left:75px;
    top:0;
}
.helper_b {
    top:75px;
    height:25px;
    width:75px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
}

.option_two, .option_three {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.option_two div {
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 255);
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
}

.white, .color {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
}

.white {
    background-color:#fff;
}
.color {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="option_one">
    <div class="helper_a"></div>
    <div class="helper_b"></div>
</div>

<div class="option_two">
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="option_three">
    <div class="white">
        <div class="color"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="first">
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Например прозрачное модальное окно. Фон затенения подмешивается к фону самого окна. При этом само окно может содержать в себе другие блоки, которым тоже хотелось бы задать прозрачный фон другого цвета.